# RSymPy - Handling multivariate equation

Tags: r, sympy

When I try to solve an equation using **RSymPy** library, I get the **NotImplementedError: multivariate equation** error.

I am not sure where am I wrong or should I use some other library for multivariate equation or is there a workaround to make it work?

Also I am not able to pass the values in the form of variables to the equation parameters (ymax, ymin and ec50) without hard coding it.

```
library(rSymPy)
ymax <- Var("ymax")
ymin <- Var("ymin")
ec50 <- Var("ec50")
sympy("var('x y')")
sympy("expr = ((y-ymin)*(ec50+x))+abs(ymax)*x")
sympy("solve(expr.subs([(ymin, 1615.72687), (ec50, 2.19835099), (ymax, -1607.73011)]),x, y)")
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What is the expected output? Seems like the input to those functions are just strings so i don't see why you couldn't just `paste()` in literal values (or `sprintf()` or whatever).

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, The stumbling block is solving the multivariate equation with the provided parameter  values in R. Is it possible?

Comment: I still don't understand what you are "solving" here. Is there an equality somewhere that i'm just missing? Are you expecting a unique point solution? Or a line? What (in words) are you trying to solve?

Comment: Was trying to plugin the values to the sympy function for plotting the equation:  ((y-ymin)*(ec50+x))+abs(ymax)*x = 0. Trying to predict the x values for various y values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** If you are trying to solve ((y-ymin)*(ec50+x))+abs(ymax)*x = 0 for x symbolically in terms of y where the other variables are known then try this:

```
library(Ryacas)

ymin <- -1607.73011
ymax <- 1615.72687
ec50 <- 2.19835099

x <- Sym("x")
y <- Sym("y")

e <- ((y-ymin)*(ec50+x))+abs(ymax)*x

Solve(e, x)
```

giving:

```
expression(list(x == -(2.19835099 * (y + 1607.73011)/(y + 3223.45698))))
```

**2)** or if you want x in terms of all other symbols then instead of substituting their values define the other variables as yacas symbols:

```
library(Ryacas)

ymax <- Sym("ymax")
ymin <- Sym("ymin")
ec50 <- Sym("ec50")
x <- Sym("x")
y <- Sym("y")

e <- ((y-ymin)*(ec50+x))+abs(ymax)*x

Solve(e, x)
```

giving:

```
expression(list(x == -((y - ymin) * ec50/(y - ymin + abs(ymax)))))
```

Read the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas/vignettes/Ryacas.pdf), the help files and run the demos that come with Ryacas if you need more info.

**3) multiroot** Rather than perform symbolic maninpulation an alternative approach is to find the root numerically using the rootSolve package:

```
library(rootSolve)

ymin <- -1607.73011
ymax <- 1615.72687
ec50 <- 2.19835099

f <- function(x, y) ((y-ymin)*(ec50+x))+abs(ymax)*x

# using x=1 as the starting value find the value of x for which y=10
y <- 10
multiroot(f, 1, y = y)
```

giving:

```
$root
[1] -1.099856

$f.root
[1] 0

$iter
[1] 3

$estim.precis
[1] 0
```

Double check using the equation we derived using Ryacas in (1):

```
-(2.19835099 * (y + 1607.73011)/(y + 3223.45698))
## [1] -1.099856
```

**3a) nlm** Actually we can do this numerically without any packages at all.  Using the same setup as in (3):

```
nlm(function(x, y) f(x, y)^2, 1, y = y)
```

**3b) uniroot**  If you are able to bracket the x value, between -10 and 10, say, then another way to do it without any packages using the same setup is as in (3) is:

```
uniroot(f, c(-10, 10), y = y)
```

**Note:**

- although the equation has two variables, x and y, this would normally be regarded as a univariate problem, not a multivariate problem, because we are solving for one variable, x, in terms of y
- in the question `ymin` exceeds `ymax` so we have exchanged them

Comment: Dear @G-Grothendieck  Thank you for your comprehensive reply. I gratefully appreciate it. I have posted a global curve fitting related question as the next step to the above mentioned query. May you kindly advice me on how to fix the issue and proceed?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465934/dose-repsone-global-curve-fitting-using-r  - Thanks!